# How to apply jQuery to a SharePoint grouped list view

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I'm trying to change the SharePoint list item "Edit" icon to a new image on a SharePoint 2007 site.  I've got it working fine by applying some jQuery to the master page.  The problem i'm having is, any list view that is configured to be "Grouped", doesn't get the new Icon because the HTML isn't rendered on document.ready.  The HTML gets added once you expand the groupings after page load.

My question is, how do you apply jQuery/Javascript to the html that gets rendered after the page load?

Here's the simple code i'm using.

```
<script language="javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img[src*='edititem.gif']").attr("src","<URL to New Img>").attr("title","Comment");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) to do this.

It would look something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("img[src*='edititem.gif']").livequery(function(){
    $(this).attr("src","").attr("title","Comment");
  });

});
```

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 and couldn't get this to work.  I don't know if it has to do with the code being in the masterpage or something else within SharePoint blocking the liveQuery (and .live) from working.  I appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try [_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2009/06/22/javascript-pageload-add-function.aspx):

```
<script language="javascript">   
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("FunctionName");   
    function FunctionName()   
    {   
        $("img[src*='edititem.gif']").attr("src","<URL to New Img>").attr("title","Comment"); 
    }   
</script>
```